# Strange error in iOS SDK with a correct JSON Stream

Tags: ios, json, parsing

I have a little problem, when i try to parse my JSON stream, i got an error catching by

```
if(error) {NSLog(@"%@",error);}
```

which tells me this

> 2013-04-14 23:53:09.979 Test[24463:303] Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The data couldn’t be read because it has been corrupted." (Unescaped control character around character 215.) UserInfo=0x10042f6c0 {NSDebugDescription=Unescaped control character around character 215.}

The problem is that my JSON stream seems to be perfect, you can find it here : http://api.kalokod.com/cce/news.json, perfect 'coz JSONLint returns that this JSON is valid.

Any idea ? Thanks !

**EDIT**

This is my parser

```
- (NSDictionary *)JSONParser:(NSString *)JSONFile {

NSError *jsonParserError;

NSURL *myJSONfileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:JSONFile];

NSString *myJSONstring = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:myJSONfileURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&jsonParserError];

if (jsonParserError) {
    NSLog(@"%@", jsonParserError);
}

NSData *jsonData = [myJSONstring dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSError *error;

NSDictionary *JSONParser = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}


return JSONParser;
```

}

Comment: Please show your code leading up to the parse error; also, can you display the contents of the JSON string just before the parse (while it may be fine when you look at it elsewhere, what matters is the contents of the string at parse time).

Comment: Make sure you are loading the JSON with the proper encoding.

Comment: @rmaddy my encoding file is OK, i'll test it with another `NSError`, @rick-trap i can print the string yes, without any pbs, so my encoding is correct.

Comment: BTW - your error checking is flawed. Don't just check if `error` is non-nil. First check the return value of the method. Example: `if (myJSONstring == nil && jsonParserError) { // log error }`.

Comment: Add a log statement showing `myJSONstring`. Point out character 215.

Comment: O_o i just added your condition and it works now awesome ! But I really don't understand... Well, thanks :-)

Comment: Just for info how can i do that ? ( Point out character 215)

Comment: 1. Read the docs for `JSONObjectWithData`. Most methods that return a value and have an `NSError` out parameter follow the same pattern. If there is an error, the return value will be `nil` and the `error` parameter may contain the error. Never check the error unless the return value of the method is `nil`. 2. Use `substringWithRange:`. Show from, say 205 - 225. Hopefully there is something obvious near the middle of that substring.

Comment: In fact i have pbs with the `'` char, i'm french, and this char is used a lot, i have to find a way to escape i in my json script (php) ;-) Thanks

Comment: Finishing the post : Ok the error is due to ' : & " symbole on my JSON

Answer (score 0):

JSON doesn't have to be UTF-8. If the JSON data is UTF-16 or UTF-32, your attempt to convert it to an NSString will go terribly wrong. Try

```
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL...]
```

and pass the data directly to JSONObjectWithData. BTW. "Cannot connect to server" is what the link gives me.